# Can fusion power production be quickly attenuated/increased, in principle?

Tags: electricity, fusion, nuclear-engineering

Today there was an [announcement](https://news.mit.edu/2021/MIT-CFS-major-advance-toward-fusion-energy-0908) of a breakthrough in the path toward fusion energy.

[This](https://youtu.be/N-yALPEpV4w?t=801) presentation by Michael Shellenberger states that a problem with wind and solar is that, because of intermittency issues, if we become dependent on solar and wind for a large part of our power, we need a power source that is easy to scale up and down as needed, to compensate for that intermittency. He points out that nuclear fission can't do that, so often the backup ends up being natural gas, which isn't carbon-free.

Does fusion face the same problem with difficulty of scaling up and down power production on the fly? I would imagine so, with the incredible temperatures involved.

Comment: Fission needs a minimum critical mass to reduce the surface area to volume ratio so neutrons don't escape too much for a critical reaction. I've seen plans for both very large and very small fusion reactors, so I'm guessing it needn't have this issue, but it depends on the reaction used. For example, deuterium-tritium reactors will need to breed tritium in a chain reaction because its global supply is small, and that's done with a surface lithium "breeding blanket", which I suppose might have the same surface area concern.

Comment: Having said that, [there are other factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_modular_reactor) keeping fission reactors big. I'd post an answer if I had the relevant expertise.

Comment: AFAIK the main thing keeping fission reactors big are statutory problems, not engineering problems. Reactors are required to have certain minimum exclusion zones, security forces, etc, that make smaller (and, ironically, safer) reactor designs economically unfeasible.

Comment: It all depends a great deal on the particular plant. But, there is nothing in principle making a large baseline carbon-neutral/free plant from ramping down - you could use the excess power to do any number of things (hydrogen production, Bitcoin mining, railgun launches to orbit, ...).

Comment: @gs Would the same concerns apply to fusion?

Comment: Probably. Nuclii are so scary we had to take the all the nuclii out of the nuclear magnetic resonance imagers before anybody would let us put NMRI... I mean, MRI machines in hospitals. Fusion and reactions are also scary, and it will be hard to take the nuclii, fusion, and reactions out of nuclear fusion reactors. If you want to see a future with fusion power, I suggest aggressive rebranding from Nuclear Fusion to Hydrogen Hugging.

Comment: "Would the same concerns apply to fusion?" In terms of _real_ (not imagined) dangers, no. A mistake in a fission reactor can cause a meltdown; a mistake in a fusion reactor would just make fusion stop, because it's so hard to keep it going. This is true even in chain-reaction examples, because one trition begetting up to two when everything's working well only serves to prevent fuel depletion; it doesn't make the fusion itself too easy.

Comment: Worth noting that we already have fission reactor designs that can't melt down even if you have Godzilla kick them over.